# Double slit experiment on superfluid surface. What do we observe?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, waves, double-slit-experiment, superfluidity

What do we observe when we perform a double slit experiment with mechanical waves on the surface of a superfluid?

Do the ripples on  the superfluid form and propagate similar to ones on water? What are the properties of the wave right after passing the slits? How does the superfluid interact with the edges? Is it possible that the interaction with the edge and the corresponding pattern would yield some information about quantum mechanics?

Comment: Do you mean the usual double slit experiment where we send light or some massive particles (electrons, etc.) through the slits, but with the whole setup immersed in a superfluid?

Comment: I think OP means sending mechanical waves on superfluids through a double slit.

Comment: why a superfluid and not a superconductor?

Comment: @Wolphramjonny As far as I know most superconductors are solid. How would you conduct double slit experiment with mechanical waves on solid mediums?

Comment: A superconductor is "just" a charged superfluid. The conduction electrons in a superconductor can be modeled as a superfluid, and one could imagine this fluid divorced from the solid crystalline lattice of nuclei. But why complicate the OP's nice question? Best to start thinking about the case of neutral superfluids and add in the complication of superconductivity later. @Wolphramjonny